# Automatic currency conversion

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I would like to add an automatic conversion thing to my spreadsheet.

I have two columns, A1 titled **Money in USD** and B1 titled **Money in BRL**.
I want to make it so whenever I enter a value in the USD column, it automatically enters the BRL value to the BRL column.

I found this:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:"USDBRL")
```

...but I don't really know how to work with it for my purpose. And basically, I don't know how to work with any functions at all.

Is that easy enough or even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDBRL")` is the value of one US dollar in Brazilian currency. This needs to be multiplied by the dollar amount that you want to convert. So, if B5 is the USD amount, the formula

```
=B5*GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDBRL")
```

will give the equivalent amount in Brazilian currency.

Comment: This no longer works in the new Google sheets. Is there a way to make it work now. I have it working on one sheet but when I ctreat a new sheet and enter in the formula it just has a message of loading?

Comment: All my answers are based on new Google sheets. I tested this just now: works fine, 100 USD is 395.905 BRL. Could be a transient issue related to holidays.